# How to autofill a form template with values stored in database in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to fill my edit_post.html with the values already stored in the database .
My edit url is `http://hostname/edit_Post/960` .   "960" corresponds to the item id in my database  . I request with that ID to update its contents.

I wann the contents to appear here :-

**edit_Post.html**

```
<form id="category_form" method="post" action="/edit_Post/">

    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}            
        {{ field.errors }}
        <input type="text" placeholder='{{ field.help_text }}'>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Post" />
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^edit_Post/(?P<id>\d+)', 'blog.views.edit_Post'),
```

**forms.py**

```
class addPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the title ")
    author = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the Author ")
    bodytext = forms.CharField(max_length=128,
                               help_text="Please enter the Body",
                               required=False)

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model=posts
        fields = ('title', 'author','bodytext')
```

finally **views.py**

```
def edit_Post(request, id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    instance=posts.objects.get(id=id)
    form = addPostForm(instance=instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addPostForm(request.POST,instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            confirmation_message = "Post information updated successfully!"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form=addPostForm(instance=instance)
    return render_to_response('edit_Post.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

my **model.py**

```
class posts(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    bodytext = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django would already do this, if you hadn't bypassed its mechanism of outputting fields. In your template you should do this:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to keep the placeholder functionality, add that in the form class itself:

```
class addPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Please enter the title'}))
```

Comment: what does this widget does ?
could you explain me the working ?

Comment: What? The widget is the default one, the only reason to specify it at all is that you want to pass it the placeholder attribute.

Comment: i am a newbie to Django.

Comment: OK, and...? As a newbie, you will of course have read the documentation, which explains exactly what widgets are and how you pass them custom attributes, no?

Comment: i have posted my template . it is edit_Post.html. 
The form is not auto filled with the values corresponding to entry ' 960 ' . Your answer didn't suffice

Comment: Yes and I *showed you above* what to do in your template. Have you done that? If you had, it will work. The stuff about the widget is not relevant to that.

Comment: well, i would like to view   the ' body ' of my Blog Post in textarea . What should i have to do to achieve this ? Couldn't I make some styles ?

Answer (score -1):

Django provides **CRUD**(Create -> CreateView, Remove ->DeleteView, Update -> UpdateView, Details -> DetailView) Views. If you can, use them. 

 You can change your method from views.py in a class.

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = posts
    form_class = addPostForm
    template = "edit_post.html"
```

Then you can add methods there :).

Comment: what are u trying to say, where should i type this code ?